# Поиск по коллекции Set

Tags: java, поиск, коллекции

У меня есть объект ролей в котором есть Set названий ролей, я хочу сделать проверку, по наличию у пользователя той или иной роли. Подскажите как лучше это сделать, чтобы было красиво и лаконично.

Roles.java:

```
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @NaturalId
    @Column(length = 60)
    private RoleName name;
```

RoleName.java:

```
public enum RoleName {
    ROLE_ADMIN,
    ROLE_MANAGER,
    ROLE_CLIENT,
    ROLE_USER,
}
```

сейчас мой поиск выглядит вот так:

```
boolean isFind = false;
        for (Role role : user.getRoles()) {
            isFind = role.getName().equals(RoleName.ROLE_CLIENT);
            if (isFind) break;
        }
```

Но мне не очень нравиться такой способ. Можете предложить вариант по лучше?

Comment: можно set.contains(Object o) или set.stream().anyMatch(role -> role.name.equals(someRoleName));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return user.getRoles()
           .stream()
           .map(Role::getName)
           .anyMatch(r -> r.equals(RoleName.ROLE_CLIENT));
```